# Access a remote mongodb with wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, mongodb

I'm trying to access a mongodb within a plugin in wordpress. I have no trouble connecting to the db through robomongo but when I use the following code in a php file in a plugin:

```
$db = new Mongo('mongodb://host:port', array(
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass'
));
```

or even just

```
$db = new Mongo();
```

The page won't even load. Thanks

EDIT:
Here is the error that wp outputted

Class 'Mongo' not found in **pathing/wp-content/plugins/nameofplugin/nameofplugin.php** on line 24

I installed mongodb with homebrew as well as php 5.6 driver for mongodb

Comment: Sorry, I've added the error message.

Comment: The error message tells you everything: You don't have a `PHP Class` called `Mongo` in your WP installation.  I'd recommend reviewing the [PHP Docs for Mongo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php) - if you follow the chain of "Deprecated" notices, you'll find that you're supposed to use [new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this one

```
$mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://host:port', 
                        array('username'=>'yourname', 'pawssword'=>'yourpwd');
$db = $mongo->yourdbname;
```

I do not know what your error. I'm sorry about that but it works for me.